# How to refer to figures, tables, equations and sections

Tags: tables, sectioning, floats, equations, typography

What is the correct way to refer to figures, tables, equations and sections?

For example, should I write
In Figure 1.1 we notice that.... or
In fig. 1.1 we notice that.... or
In figure 1.1 we notice that....

Same thing for tables.
In Table/tab./table 1.1 we notice that....

In Eq./Equation/eq./equation (1.1) we notice that....

I've seen different approaches in various books and I don't know which is the typographically correct way.

As we mentioned in Section/section/sec. 1.1 blah blah blah....

EDIT (clarification): 
I'd like to know what is the right look, not how to produce this result.
I think I like the abbreviation with capital letter or the non abbreviated form but without capital letter. But I don't know which one is correct, if any. 
Also, I'm talking about a book or a thesis.

Comment: Do you want to know how you can change the appearance in LaTeX, or what should be the right look after all?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you could clarify your question as @Johannes_B has asked, that would be helpful. If it's about changing the appearance in LaTeX, we can help you, otherwise this question might be off topic, as it will possibly be opinion based and based on particular disciplines and established practices.

Comment: Great question! Whichever way you choose, the `cleveref` will help you make the changes globally

Comment: Great question! It's something I've wondered as well. As a reader, I strongly disagree with the capitalization; "In Table 1 we see that..." looks very very very very very wrong to my eyes. IMHO if it's in the middle of a sentence, it should be in lower case and non-abbreviated (so, "In table 1 we see that..."). Because why on earth should it defy the English language rules? But that could be a language/cultural dependent thing.

Comment: `fancyref` is another option. I remember I considered switching to `cleveref` as it does some things `fancyref` doesn't but then I found out there was something even more important (to me) which it couldn't do so I've stuck where I am.

Comment: Now the question has been clarified, it seems to be off-topic since it is about correct typography rather than how to achieve that in TeX and friends. That is, it is entirely independent of TeX.

Comment: Several questions about typography have been asked on this website in the past (see per the tag), and were not closed because, while they might not be TeX related, they also don't usually belong on the language SX, and no one except TeX users and a couple of book designers give a damn about *practical* typography anyway. So I would support keeping that question open, and will try to provide an answer tomorrow.

Comment: This question could be migrated to [Academia.sx](http://academia.stackexchange.com/) for an answer

Comment: Alex, could you please try to rephrase your question so as to make it more specific and objective. Like: what would be considered a best practise if no style guidelines are imposed, and how to best automatise it (packages and macros, for those who don't use LaTeX). That way, I think the question could reasonably be reopened. As I said before, I believe such very practical typography questions belong here, if only because no one will answer them sensibly elsewhere.

Answer (score 10):

As a matter of fact, the "right" answer is:

**depends of what you want to do with your document!**

For example, I wrote a paper for *Phys. Rev.* and they like the abbreviated form for sections, equations and figures... but long form for appendices and table. Latter I wrote another paper for *Mod. Phys. Lett.* and the format is different.

Nonetheless, As a matter of consistency **always use a capitalized version of the word*... e.g., use `Eq.` intead of `eq.` or use `Tab.` instead of `tab.`, because those environment with captions put names (such as `Figure 1`) capitalized.

Another general recommendation is to use unbreakable spaces between the name and the number, e.g., `It was mentioned on Sec.~\ref{sec:analysis} that...` because it avoid that the number goes to the next line if you run out of space after the name.

Although this is far to be "correct" or a complete answer, I hope you find it useful!!!

Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

The style guidelines for where the work is being published will decide what you should use. Alternatively if there is no style guidelines you can make your own choice. In my opinion the best way to do this for work that might have to conform to multiple style guides is the `\autoref` command. Some classes will automatically provide the right style. Alternatively you can change them in the preamble yourself via `\renewcommand*{\sectionautorefname}{Section}`.